# jQuery transfer data between tables via textbox input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, html-table

I asked a question yesterday and that got me going on the right path, but I'm absolutely stuck again.

Outline:

I have 3 tables;

table 1 - expected data (#expected)

table 2 - expected confirmed data (#scannedExp)

table 3 - unexpected confirmed data (#scannedUnExp)

So for a example..
if I was to enter "6666" in the input box
it would reduce qty in the "#expected" table by 1 but create a column in the "#scannedExp" table with qty of 1 (with the i.e desc, cage grabbed from the #expected table).

if we was to enter '6666' this time it would delete the "#expected" row, but increase the table "#scannedExp"

if again we was to enter '6666' this time it would add a row to "#scannedUnExp" with just the code and qty (dont need the desc or cage)

and if we was to enter say "1234" it would add a row in "#scannedUnExp"

for some reason my codes not working in Jsfiddle as it works to some extent in my browser.

http://jsfiddle.net/j3psmmo3/

```
    <body>
  <input type="text" style="width: 200px" id="code" name="code" />
<input id = "btnSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit"/>

<P>Scanned Expected</P>  
<table id = "scannedExp" > <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Desc</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Cage</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
<P>Scanned Un Expected</P>   
<table id = "scannedUnExp" > <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Cage</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
</table>
    <P>Data Expected</P>
    <table id = "expected"> <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
                <th>Desc</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Cage</th>

            </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="4444" >
            <td>4444</td>
            <th>Car Door</th>
            <td>3</td>
            <th>S2222</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="5555" >
            <td>5555</td>
            <th>door handel</th>
            <td>1</td>
            <th>S2222</th>

        </tr>
        <tr id="6666" >
            <td>6666</td>
            <th>headlight</th>
            <td>2</td>
            <th>S2222</th>

        </tr>
        <tr id="7777">
            <td>7777</td>
            <th>seat</th>
            <td>5</td>
            <th>S2222</th>

        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>


</body>
```

my javascript

```
 $(window).load(function(){
$("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(){
    numRows = $("#expected tr").length; //loop thought expected data
    for(var i=1 ; i<numRows ; i++){ 
        var code = $("#expected tr:nth-child(" + i + ") td:nth-child(1)").html();
        var desc = $("#expected tr:nth-child(" + i + ") td:nth-child(2)").html();
        var qty = $("#expected tr:nth-child(" + i + ") td:nth-child(3)").html();
        var cage = $("#expected tr:nth-child(" + i + ") td:nth-child(4)").html();


            // if code is in expected data -1 from qty col
            if(code == $("#code").val()){    
            $("#expected tr:nth-child(" + i + ") td:nth-child(3)").html(parseInt(qty) - 1);

            //delete if last one in expected table
            if(qty ==1 ){$("#" + code).remove();} 


            // loop thought scanned expected table
            numRowsB = $("#scannedExp tr").length; 
            for(var ib=1 ; ib<numRows ; ib++){   
            var codeExp = $("#scannedExp tr:nth-child(" + ib + ") td:nth-child(1)").html();
            var qtyExp = $("#scannedExp tr:nth-child(" + ib + ") td:nth-child(3)").html();    

            // if in scannedExp add qty by one
            if(codeExp == $("#code").val()){   
            $("#scannedExp tr:nth-child(" + ib + ") td:nth-child(3)").html(parseInt(qtyExp) + 1);
            return true;
            }

            else{ //if not found in expected table add row to scannedExp
            $("#scannedExp tbody").append("<tr><td>" + $("#code").val() + "</td><td>" + desc + "</td><td>1</td><td>" + cage + "</td></tr>");
            return true;
            }
            } 
            return true;
            }
            else{
            alert("not in expected");
            }


}})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed from your fiddle that the button does not trigger the click event.

Your code had 3 problems that I have fixed and then the code worked fine.

**First**
I think you meant to use `$(document).ready()` instead of `$(window).load()`.
Since you want to listen to events, it is better to wait until all DOM elements are loaded and the `document` is `ready` before attempting to do anything else.

But since the event trigger I am about to tell you about in my second point does not depend on the document being ready or not, it is not necessary. So I removed it.

**Second:**

I modified the code to use `$(document).on('click','selector',function(){});` instead of `$(element).on('click',function(){});`

```
//Use this event
$(document).on('click','#btnSubmit',function(){
   ...
   ...
});

//Instead of using this
$("#btnSubmit").on("click", function(){
   ...
   ...
});
```

the .on() I used will work for DOM controls that have been loaded from the page, or ones that you added dynamically. That's why I rely on it all the time.

**Third**
You forgot a semi-colon at the last line of your code...

```
   ...
   ...
   else{
            alert("not in expected");
            }


}})     //  <-- This line has no semi-colon
});
```

You may check the modified code on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s4q1hu5q/1/)

The code works fine after the modification.